# Rename inkfilepicker file on upload to s3

Tags: javascript, upload, amazon-s3

I have an app using inkfilepicker and we need to be able to rename an image to be saved as XYZ_{{variable1}}_{{variable2}}_imagename.jpg. For some reason filename will not working correctly on the save. If anyone can think of how to rename files before they get put into s3, it'd be greatly appreciated!